# Route public incoming traffic to another server using WireGuard

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

There are 2 Windows servers, Server-A & Server-B.
Server-A is directly connected to the internet with IP-1 & IP-2.
Server-B is connected to the internet with IP-3, behind a NAT router.

I would like to setup WireGuard to forward all public traffic coming in at Server-A at IP-2 to Server-B to be handled by IIS on Server-B.
Public traffic coming in at Server-A at IP-1 should continue to be handled by IIS on Server-A.

The Server-A WireGuard config is this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ***
ListenPort = 51820
Address = 10.2.2.1/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = <Server-B-Public-Key>
AllowedIPs = <IP-2>/32
```

The Server-B WireGuard config is this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ***
Address = <IP-2>/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = <Server-A-Public-Key>
AllowedIPs = 10.2.2.1/32
Endpoint = <IP-1>:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

The VPN connects OK, I can see the handshakes.
However traffic coming in at IP-2 continues to be handled by IIS on Server-A, instead of by Server-B.

Comment: Did you actually deassign the IP address from Server A? Does Server A support IP routing?

Comment: @user1686 We should I have to deassign it? Why can't I route it to Server-B?
Server-A is WIndows, so it supports the `route` command.

Comment: Generally because local assignments take priority over routes elsewhere, and because you'd have two servers with the same IP address.

Comment: Well, I can't deassign IP-2 from Server-A, because then the traffic wouldn't get there at all. Are you saying that what I'm trying to do is impossible? BTW the primary IP address of Server-A is IP-1, so I wouldn't say that there are 2 servers with IP-2.

Comment: Then you'd need either "proxy ARP" or have your provider route IP-2's traffic via IP-1 (instead of both being on-link), so that the traffic would get there. Primary vs non-primary doesn't really change anything at all; if the address is assigned to the system, then it's assigned to the system.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Could you give me a link explaining how to do `proxy ARP` on Windows, or would you know if Vultr (my provider) has a way of routing IP-2's traffic via IP-1?

Comment: I've found docs saying that Windows is capable of proxy-ARP (without needing third-party software, that is), but at the moment not sure how to activate that feature (it's in iphlp). I'm guessing it might be in netsh. I'll post a full answer if I actually find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the address needs to be routed to another host, then it cannot also be assigned to this host, as that will have priority over your custom route.

So you need to unassign the address from Server-A's network interface, then use proxy-ARP to make Vultr still send you traffic for that address (i.e. respond to ARP queries for an address that isn't assigned).

But although the [functionality](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-createproxyarpentry) is present in Windows, I couldn't find any CLI interface for it (apparently it's there only for built-in RAS VPNs), I guess it could still be called via powershell by using P/Invoke, or from a C program. There might also be third-party proxy-ARP tools for Windows, too; haven't looked for any yet.

(I would suggest using Linux or FreeBSD as your "router" server – not Windows. The latter is *technically* capable of IP routing, but is severely lacking in functionality when trying to do things beyond the built-in RAS and ICS features.)

As an alternative, if all traffic is based on HTTP or HTTPS, you could configure a web server on Server-A to act as a "reverse proxy" and forward requests at HTTP level. Both IIS and Apache can act as reverse proxies.

For other TCP traffic, Windows also has a built-in proxy under `netsh portproxy` which could forward TCP connections. The downside of using this feature is that your Server-B will always see Server-A as the source of all connections.

Comment: I'd argue that the source IP being replaced by *portproxy* is actually a feature. Because otherwise, server B would most likely attempt to send its response traffic directly to the source, not through the VPN tunnel.